# Diagnosing Engine Knock

Tags: engine, oil, alternator, knock

My 2003 Volvo XC70 had a slight engine knock for about 5000 miles but never showed any signs of damage to the engine. Oil was fine and it only made the sound in around the 2500-3500 rpm range.

One day I was driving back on the interstate and the check engine light came on and after being scanned (not certain the OBD II code) it showed that the alternator wasn’t functioning properly, and the car had a slowed crank speed.

After having this checked and continuing on,  at ~100 into my trip I heard a small “bang” so to speak and the engine knocking became very loud, I immediately shifted into neutral, turned the car off, and veered off the highway into the shoulder.

Doing some research I believed it to be the oil pump, but for this to be the case I don’t think it would go out so suddenly like that.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance

P.S. Earlier that day when I ran into the alternator problem, the power steering started to squeal and even boil, but after stopping and restarting the car this quit. There was no sign of a leak in power steering fluid and the reservoir was full.

Comment: An oil pump can fail catastrophically : the shaft can break for example...

Comment: is there oil pressure?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: @Ben Nope, no oil pressure.

Comment: To clarify, you're saying there's absolutely no oil pressure, or maybe there's no oil pressure light? If no oil pressure, that in and of itself is a huge (obvious) issue.

Comment: A friend of mine has an s60 with a "fickle" oil pump. If he doesn't blip the throttle immediately after starting, the engine never develops any oil pressure. This caused him some nuisance recently when he started the car to defrost, forgot to blip and went back in the house. He returned to a very laboured sounding engine; still goes though ! I forget what he said the fault with the pump was, but suffice to say they clearly have their foibles and it should probably be first on your checklist if you're not getting any pressure, after assessing oil level, of course!